# User's name doesn't update in header after login

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I am using CodeIgniter + Registration/Login script from HTML Form Guide. I wanted to have user's name displayed in the navbar (logged in as: [username]). So in controllers I've added a variable:

```
$data['login'] = '';

$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/nav', $data);
$this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
```

and in the nav.php :

```
<?php
if ($login!='')
    echo "Logged in as: ".$login;
?>
```

In the Access Controlled Page, which is loaded after login:

```
$login = $fgmembersite->UserFullName();
```

which is:

```
function UserFullName()
    {
        return isset($_SESSION['name_of_user'])?$_SESSION['name_of_user']:'';
    }
```

User's name is correctly returned in Access Controlled Page, but not in the navbar. I believe it is because of the order that views are loaded. Before `templates/nav` is loaded, the variable `$data['login']` is probably being cleared according to what I declared in controllers. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: could it be that you are setting `$data['login'] = '';` before loading the views causing your views `$login='';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to add `$data['login']` in your controller anyways? If you have your user logged in you must have put that information in your session right? If not just save the name of the logged-in user in the session first.Eg.

```
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_user_name', $username);
```

Now, in the pages where you want to show the name just do this:

```
if( $this->session->userdata('logged_user_name') ){
    echo $this->session->userdata('logged_user_name');
}
```

Comment: right, I can just use `$_SESSION['name_of_user']`, but I needed to add `session_start()` before that.

Comment: Just `session_start()` in your `constructor`.

Comment: `constructor`? which one? you meant `controller`?

Comment: yep in your controller's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following **order** of code segments-

### code segment1:

```
$data['login'] = '';

$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/nav', $data);
$this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
```

### code segment2:

```
function UserFullName()
{
    return isset($_SESSION['name_of_user'])?$_SESSION['name_of_user']:'';
}
```

### code segment3:

```
$login = $fgmembersite->UserFullName();
```

### code segment4:

```
<?php
    if ($login!='')
        echo "Logged in as: ".$login;
?>
```

Comment: this doesn't make sense, since all of these 4 code segments are in different files and changing the order would be an overkill, if possible at all.

Comment: @OverdrivenFall anyway, are you following this order of execution???
Because proper ordering is needed for what you want to do. That's what I want to say.